# LOGIN into facebook or google from another domain

Tags: facebook, authentication, request

I there anyway to log users to facebook and google gmail, from another domain site?

Or are there specific API to do that?

I'm not talking about fb login or connect or google login API, i'm talking about "triggering" login forms in some whay or launch requests to sites to login in users.

I would like to make users able to log to facebook from another site, setting up cookies, so when he will return to facebook he will be logged, and viceversa.

And if is there, is it legal or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not possible, since Facebook are the ones that issue the cookies, I think it might be possible to generate a cookie that will log you into Facebook, but it would be illegal. Swift

Comment: Both, Facebook and Google, use their in house database to check passwords and issue cookies, the only way to login without using that method, would be to spoof a cookie, but thats illegal so no, its not possible for either. Swift